# Devolver el valor máximo de todos los campos en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo este ejercicio de SQL que no he podido resolver, espero puedan ayudarme. La consulta es esta:

> Comparar las diferencias entre el uso de **WHERE** y **HAVING**: Mostrar las escuelas y la nota
> máxima para cada una siempre y cuando sean mayores o iguales a 7.

Las tablas son estas:

```
CREATE TABLE `escuelas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capacidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_escuela` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `legajo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nota` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_escuela`) REFERENCES `escuelas`(`id`)
);
```

Yo hice la siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
     MAX(alumnos.nota) AS 'Nota maxima',
     escuelas.nombre AS 'Escuela' 
FROM
     alumnos 
INNER JOIN escuelas on escuelas.id = alumnos.id
```

Pero solo me devuelve UNA sola escuela con su nota maxima. No se como hacer para que me devuelva la nota máxima pero de TODAS las escuelas.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para eso, deberias agrupar por escuela.. esa parte ya la viste? group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira con la siguiente consulta logré hacer lo que querías

```
SELECT escuelas.nombre, MAX(nota) FROM `escuelas`
INNER JOIN alumnos
ON escuelas.id = alumnos.id_escuela
GROUP BY escuelas.id
```

el resultado que me trajo es el siguiente, obviamente tu después debes del select debes recuperar todos los datos que necesites

[image: SQL]